# Views are getting overlapped in ios

Tags: iphone, ios6

This is my main screen where I added a table view.Now the problem arises when I click any of the tab ,my tab bar controller views is getting overlapped by the main view controller .
I need to resolve this error.
. If you didn't get my question correctly,please let me know.
Thanks

[image: image 1![image2![image3]

In Appdelegate I didn't write any code.

```
//MainViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     getValuesFormDatabase=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self getAllRowsFromTableNamed];
    [self getRefershToken];

}

//tab bar items
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {

    switch(item.tag){
        case 1:
            if (homeViewController == nil) {
                self.homeViewController =
                [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:homeViewController bundle:nil];
            }
            [self.view insertSubview:homeViewController.view belowSubview:myTabBar];
            if (currentViewController != nil)
                [currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
            currentViewController = homeViewController;
            break;


      case 2:
    if (top25ViewController == nil)
    {
        self.top25ViewController =
        [[Top25ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:top25ViewController bundle:nil];
    }
    [self.view insertSubview:top25ViewController.view belowSubview:myTabBar];
    [ALToastView toastInView:self.view withText:@"Server is not responding"];
                if (currentViewController != nil)
        [currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    currentViewController = top25ViewController;
    break;

        case 3:
            if (myfavViewController == nil) {
                self.myfavViewController =
                [[MyFavViewController alloc] initWithNibName:myfavViewController bundle:nil];
            }
            [self.view insertSubview:myfavViewController.view belowSubview:myTabBar];
            if (currentViewController != nil)
                [currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
            currentViewController = myfavViewController;
            break;

        case 4:
            if (moreViewController == nil) {
                self.moreViewController =
                [[MoreViewController alloc] initWithNibName:moreViewController bundle:nil];
            }
            [self.view insertSubview:moreViewController.view belowSubview:myTabBar];
            if (currentViewController != nil)
                [currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
            currentViewController = moreViewController;
            break;
    }
 }
//table view
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{


    return [getValuesFormDatabase count];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Cell";

MainCell *cell = (MainCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

   if (cell==nil) {

         cell=[[MainCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    }

    cell.mainViewChannelName.text=[TableChannelNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.mainViewVideoName.text=[TableVideoNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: Until and unless I saw your code it's not possible to find out the error.

Comment: I am using storyboard in which I used navigation controller which navigates to MainViewController and I used tabs which are always present at the bottom of the screen throughout the apps.Now problems comes when I click any of the tabs ,then that particular tab view is be presented,but it is getting overlapped by MainViewController,which I don't want .

Comment: Why are you adding and presenting the child view controllers yourself instead of using a tab bar controller?